# ad type id for Windows store Advertising SDK

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I had a link to the list of ad types and sizes for the AdControl, but I just can't find it again. Does anybody have that link. I need to change it back from an image ad to a text add.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. This is the list of recommended sizes and types of ads for the AdControl Windows Store Advertising SDK. (i.e. text ad, image ad, video ad etc). Note that this refers to TEST mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-test-mode-values(v=msads.10).aspx